# Reading numbers from a file in sets of 6 into a 2x3 matrix?

Tags: c, loops, matrix, scanf

I have to find the distance between two pairs of points, each point defined by three coordinates, using the function dist(double p[2][3]).
I put the total 12 coordinates in a file, separating them with a space.
I tried doing it like this but the loop never breaks, it just keeps printing the distance between the first two points over and over...

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double dist(double p[2][3])
{
    double distance=sqrt(((p[0][0]-p[1][0])*(p[0][0]-p[1][0]))+((p[0][1]-p[1][1])*(p[0][1]-p[1][1]))+((p[0][2]-p[1][2])*(p[0][2]-p[1][2])));
    return distance;
}

int main()
{
    double p[2][3];
    FILE*in;
    in=fopen("file","r");

    while(1)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(fscanf(in, "%lf ", &p[i][j])==EOF)
                    {break;}
            }
        }
        printf("the distance is %lf\n", dist(p));
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

Comment: how is this file? could you provide a small part of it please?

Comment: Sure! it's just a text file, like this.

    2.0 4.0 7.0 1.5 6.7 9.1 2.0 4.0 7.0 1.5 6.7 9.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The break inside the inner if{} only breaks the for-loop, but there is another while(1) loop that doesn't break, so the loop just keeps going and going. In the beginning of the for-loop you define and initialize "i" and "j" from scratch, so it can be another logical mistake. A good idea is to place a debug point and see how it goes.

Comment: i and j have to be defined from scratch

Comment: Got it! Thank you so much!!

Comment: @BrunoBraga, they can be defined at the beginning and later be used, that way they will not be initialized more than once. either way, it is solved.

Answer (score 0):

the problem was indeed your while loop, the break statement was only breaking the inner for loop, check this solution.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

double dist(double p[2][3])
{
    double distance=((p[0][0]-p[1][0])*(p[0][0]-p[1][0]))+((p[0][1]-p[1][1])*(p[0][1]-p[1][1]))+((p[0][2]-p[1][2])*(p[0][2]-p[1][2]));
    return distance;
}

int main()
{
    double p[2][3];
    FILE*in;
    in=fopen("file","r");
    int flag = 1;
    while(flag > 0)
    {
        for(int i=0;i<2;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++)
            {
                if(fscanf(in, "%lf ", &p[i][j])==EOF)
                    {flag = 0;}
            }
        }
        printf("the distance is %lf\n", dist(p));
    }
    fclose(in);
}
```

Comment: Yes that was the problem! Thank you, I hadn’t thought about using a flag variable!